# How to add class to index.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, console-application, html.dropdownlistfor

I need to create drop down list that includes 5 different cities using `yield return new SelectListItem`

This is a part of the code in my newly made class called `listOfCities`

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetItems()
{
    List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
    list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "City", Value = "City" });
    SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem();
    yield return new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "London",
        Value = "London"
    };
```

This is my code in index.cshtml

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.City,listOfCities.GetItems())
```

When I write this code, it gives me:

> THE NAME 'listOfCities' DOES NOT EXIST IN THE CURRENT CONTEXT

Where is the problem?

Comment: you should have been returning `list`.. why are you using yield and returning a new instance?

Comment: @dotNETbeginner even if i delete the list, it doesn't work. (the instructions say i need to use yield)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `using` for the namespace for your `listOfCities` class in the view.

```
@using My.Namespace;

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.City,listOfCities.GetItems())
```

Or write out the full namespace

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.City, My.Namespace.listOfCities.GetItems())
```

Comment: I have already tried this but it gives me 2 errors ---> **Error 1 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dsr_vaja3.Models.PersonDetails>' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>)' has some invalid arguments**

Comment: And... **Error 2 Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>'**

Comment: Seems you are referencing two `SelectListItem` classes. You probably want `System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem`.

Comment: It still doesn't fix my problem

Comment: @dotNETbeginner it is the same. ... **System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem** doesn't rly work for me

Comment: Maybe you should post the whole listOfCities class (including the libraries used) so that we can examine what's happening. From my view, if `SelectListItem` is `System.Web.Mvc`, this should work.